# Set Calendar Date to Current Date

Tags: java, android

I have variable with value of `timeInMills` which is past 3 days ago, I wanted to reset the date of it to current date but the time should be still.

```
Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calSets = (Calendar)calNow.clone();

calSets.setTimeInMillis(TIME_IN_MILL); //set datetime from timeInMillis
//Reset the date to current Date.
```

How to do that?

Comment: You shouldn't use the `Calendar` class. It's obsolete.

Comment: @MCEmperor - Why is that?

Comment: [Because of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset a `Calendar` by calling `setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis())`:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // Just for testing

final long TIME_IN_MILL = 1563204600000L; // 2019-07-15 15:30 UTC

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(TIME_IN_MILL);
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); // Reset
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(cal.getTime()));
```

The code prints `2019-07-18 15:30:00.000`, which is todays date with the time of day from the `TIME_IN_MILL` value.

If you don't want to rely on `System.currentTimeMillis()`, just get the value from the `Calendar` object, first thing:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
long now = cal.getTimeInMillis();

cal.setTimeInMillis(TIME_IN_MILL);
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

cal.setTimeInMillis(now);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this, get the properties you want, before you change the instance:

```
Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calSets = (Calendar)calNow.clone();

int hours = calNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
int minutes = calNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

calSets.setTimeInMillis(TIME_IN_MILL); //set datetime from timeInMillis
//Reset the date to current Date.

calSets.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calSets.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
calSets.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
calSets.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
```

Comment: I need the hours and minutes from TIME_IN_MILL not from the Current Time, is that correct?

Comment: I have made some changes from my question please see it.

Comment: do the same thing, I have shown. Except take the date (day, month, year) off the current time now (instead of the hours and minutes) and set it on the `calSets` time

Comment: No need for 2 Calendar objects. Isn't that the point of the "before you change the instance" part of the answer?